# Sub Views Not in Being Laid Out Correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm having an issue with my views not being laid out correctly on various device sizes. On 3.5" and 4" devices, the bottom buttons aren't able to be seen and on 4.7" and 5.5" they aren't at the bottom. I know it's something wrong with my auto layout constraints. Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What constraints have you added to them?

Comment: I reset them to suggested constraints just now to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is taller for some phones, hence button view go out of screen. For such situations you can (out of many many options)

1. Put all your content in scroll view. OR
2. Split your content into three views A,B,C. Put your logo in A view, textfields and sign in button in B and create account and forgot pass button in C. Pin A view to Top B at centre and C at bottom.
   Note: On small screen your view might collapse in each other. You might have to reduce the spacing further. OR
3. Update VERTICAL constraints between A B and C as per device height, so to accommodate them all.
4. Use UIStackView, [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views) is more info about UIStackView

**Tip**: You can use Xcode's Preview feature, to check if your layout is as per requirement without running the application. Open 'Assistant Editor' on the editor's top bar tap 'Automatic' or two intersecting circles and choose preview. Here you can toggle screen sizes and see how your layout responds.